# How to import JSON to MongoDB Atlas and set filed types from Realm function?

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to import data with JSON format to Atlas as is. In most cases it works as expected but in some cases values come as ceil and are imported as `Int` instead of `Double`. This prevents those records from being imported by sync:

```
MongoEncodingError Error - Apr 03 7:14:04+03:00
Error:

Failed to apply MongoDB change event to sync history
Source:

Error syncing MongoDB write
Logs:
[
  "Change Event Type: insert",
  "Namespace: public-data.previous-day-prices",
  "Partition: P",
  "Document ID: JAZZ",
  "Detailed Error: could not convert MongoDB value to Realm payload for { table: PreviousDayPriceRealmModel, path: close }, value=168 : cannot transform int value for non-int property of type double"
]
```

I tried to search for a way to somehow disambiguate the type but both `NumberDecimal` and `Decimal128` not defined in the Realm functions so it looks like the only way is to first add the data and then fix the field type but it just doesn't look right. Am I miss something? I'm new to MongoDB, Realm Sync, and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I [finally found](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/json-and-bson/#bson.double) the needed type it's `BSON.Double`

```
json.doubleField = BSON.Double(json.doubleField);
```